# Real estate website scrape with linksusing Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to use Python and Beautifulsoup to scrape a commercial real estate website with the corresponding href also shown in the final csv list. But the link column is always shown empty. How could I extract the href and schedule this task run through the whole website weekly? Thank you in advance!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer
import re


url = "https://objektvision.se/lediga_lokaler/stockholm/city"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('a', class_ ="ov--list-item d-flex")

with open('lokal_stockholm_city_v11.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['title', 'location', 'area','link']
    thewriter.writerow(header)
    
    
    for list in lists:
        title = list.find('div', class_="font-weight-bold text-ov street-address").text.replace('\r\n','')
        location = list.find('div', class_="text-ov-dark-grey area-address").text.replace('\r\n','')
        area = list.find('div', class_="font-weight-bold size").text.replace('\r\n','')
        link =list.find('a', attrs_={'href': re.compile("^https://objektvision.se/Beskriv/")})
            
       
      
        info = [title,location, area,link]
        thewriter.writerow(info)
```

[The final csv looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTQWy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Focused on* - Getting the `href` there are two points you should be aware - The `href` in your `soup` do not start with domain, they are relativ and you do not need to find the `<a>` cause you allready processing it based on your `ResultSet`.

So to get you `href` call `.get('href)` or `['href]` directly and concat it with base url:

```
    link = 'https://objektvision.se/'+e['href']
```

#### Example

**Note:** *Do not use `list` as variable name - changed it to `e` for element*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url = "https://objektvision.se/lediga_lokaler/stockholm/city"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('a', class_ ="ov--list-item d-flex")

with open('lokal_stockholm_city_v11.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['title', 'location', 'area','link']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for e in lists:
        title = e.find('div', class_="font-weight-bold text-ov street-address").text.replace('\r\n','')
        location = e.find('div', class_="text-ov-dark-grey area-address").text.replace('\r\n','')
        area = e.find('div', class_="font-weight-bold size").text.replace('\r\n','')
        link = 'https://objektvision.se/'+e['href']

        info = [title,location, area,link]
        thewriter.writerow(info)
```

#### Output

| title | location | area | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kungsgatan 49 | City , Stockholm | 923 m² | https://objektvision.se//Beskriv/218003079?IsPremium=True |
| Sveavägen 20 | City , Stockholm | 1 000 - 2 200 m² | https://objektvision.se//Beskriv/218017049?IsPremium=True |
| Sergelgatan 8-14/Sveavägen 5-9 /Mäste... | City , Stockholm | 1 373 m² | https://objektvision.se//Beskriv/218030745?IsPremium=True |
| Adolf Fredriks Kyrkogata 13 | Stockholm | 191 m² | https://objektvision.se//Beskriv/218031939 |
| Arena Sergel - Malmskillnadsgatan 36 | City , Stockholm | 1 - 3 000 m² | https://objektvision.se//Beskriv/218006788 |